# how to select different sample in each loop from a population in matlab

Tags: matlab

i have a sequence

```
A = [1:5]
```

then i did its random permutation

```
B =perms(A);
C = B(randperm(size(B,1)), :)
```

then i select a random sample from the whole population with a 5 rows as follow

```
sample = C(1:5,1:5)
```

now i did my operation on each row in the sample,

now my problem occurs when i want to select a new sample from a population, but my code select the same sample again and again until my condition ends,
here is my code ,

```
clc

clear all

A=[1:5]

B=perms(A);

C = B(randperm(size(B,1)), :)

value_of_cmax = zeros(1,5);

for P=1:24

if P<= 24

sample = C(1:5,1:5)

sample_shuffled = sample(randperm(5),:)

below my operation on each row in sample

else
end
```

NOW if the loop goes again for second time, it takes again the sample sample.. not new. :(

Comment: I can not reproduce that behavior.  Also, the `if` is completely unnecesary. The hwole idea of a for loop is that will execute until `P>24` so `if P<=24` does nothing, it will always be

Comment: so what should i do to reproduce a new sample and repeat my operation on a new sample ?

Comment: What my comment means is "In my computer, it gives me different samples"

Comment: ok i got it, i think i have to use a random code instead of                    sample = C(1:5,1:5)                  , how can i use "random"  in this specific code line   sample = C(1:5,1:5)   ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're not updating the value of sample, and you're using the same value of sample again and again !

If I've understood your question correctly then this may help:

```
clc
clear all

A=[1:5]
B=perms(A);

value_of_cmax = zeros(1,5);

for P=1:24
  C = B(randperm(size(B,1)), :);
  sample = C(1:5,1:5)

  if P<= 24
    sample_shuffled = sample(randperm(5),:)
  else end
end
```

Comment: Sam,  ur code just randomize the same sample in next loop,  it does not take a new sample from a population  :(

Comment: yeah now this helps as you randomize the whole population in each loop and then sample is taken with different values,  thanks Sam